error ''undefigned symbol: lua_rawgetp'' while trying to bind a love project with rust
I have a love2d project where I am trying to bind midi controllers with rust and mlua rust library,
I have this file configuration :
.
├── conf.lua
├── data/
├── fonts/
├── icon.png
├── images/
├── lib
│   ├── bump/
│   ├── discordRPC/
│   ├── gamepadguesser/
│   └── midi_input_handler
│       ├── Cargo.lock
│       ├── Cargo.toml
│       ├── libmidi_input_handler.so
│       ├── makefile
│       ├── src
│       │   ├── lib.rs
│       │   └── midi_handler.rs
│       └── target
│           ├── CACHEDIR.TAG
│           └── debug
│               ├── build
│               │   ├── alsa-sys-77e1bf3e25c0debe/
│               │   ├── alsa-sys-b741dd268b3e925f/
│               │   ├── libc-a02a8f1a1757eae3/
│               │   ├── libc-c87ef9fe5c4c07ea/
│               │   ├── mlua-sys-54611b35a16a6525/
│               │   ├── mlua-sys-620da340fb195242/
│               │   ├── num-traits-88de8cf05bbdf5ea/
│               │   ├── num-traits-bc09a7d6340429b8/
│               │   ├── proc-macro2-590fdbef782f5a29/
│               │   └── proc-macro2-c2a63acaec6ca8e8/
│               ├── deps/
│               ├── examples/.
│               ├── incremental/
│               ├── libmidi_input_handler.d
│               └── libmidi_input_handler.so
├── main.lua
├── makefile
├── makelove.toml
├── README.md
├── scripts
|   .
│   ├── input
│   │   ├── input_action_state.lua
│   │   ├── input_button.lua
│   │   ├── input.lua
│   │   ├── input_midi.lua
│   │   ├── input_profile.lua
│   │   └── input_user.lua
|   .
|   :
├── sfx/
└── test.toml

and lib.rs :
use crate::midi_handler::*;
use mlua::prelude::*;
use std::thread;


//same name as the lib (path include...)
#[mlua::lua_module] fn libmidi_input_handler(lua: &Lua) -> LuaResult<LuaTable> {lua_init(lua)}
#[mlua::lua_module] fn target_debug_libmidi_input_handler(lua: &Lua) -> LuaResult<LuaTable> {lua_init(lua)}
#[mlua::lua_module] fn libmidi_input_handler_libmidi_input_handler(lua: &Lua) -> LuaResult<LuaTable> {lua_init(lua)}

#[mlua::lua_module] fn lib_midi_input_handler_libmidi_input_handler(lua: &Lua) -> LuaResult<LuaTable> {lua_init(lua)}

#[mlua::lua_module]
fn lua_init(lua: &Lua) -> LuaResult<LuaTable> {
    let exports = lua.create_table()?;
    exports.set("print_rust", lua.create_function(lua_print_rust)?)?;
    exports.set("innit_midi", lua.create_function(lua_innit_midi)?)?;
    Ok(exports)
}

//test function
fn lua_print_rust(_: &Lua, message: String) -> LuaResult<()> {
    println!("[rust] {message}");
    Ok(())
}

//function that I want to use
fn lua_innit_midi(_: &Lua, _: ()) -> LuaResult<()> {
    thread::spawn(|| {init();});

    Ok(())
}


when I do
local midi = require("lib.midi_input_handler.libmidi_input_handler")

In input_user.lua.
I have this error message :
./lib/midi_input_handler/libmidi_input_handler.so: undefined symbol: lua_rawgetp

I tried to change my cargo.toml, but it did not change anything (my actual cargo.toml) :
[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib"]

[dependencies]
midi-control = "0.2.2"
midir = "0.10.0"
mlua = { version = "0.9.7", features = ["lua54", "module"] }


(sorry for that much of code, I don't really know how to give enough element without giving that much)

Are you sure you are running lua 5.4?

I was running with lua54, I tried with luajit (with features modified in the cargo.toml), and it works, after that, it was working with lua54.
I don't know what was the problem, but it solved by itself.
